# Copy-on-write Confusion: Don't all Processes write to memory anyways?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel

Copy on write in the Linux kernel allocates memory for a process when it attempts to write to a page that is referenced by a different process. This is an optimization because allocating pages every time a process is forked is expensive. However, the thing that I am confused about is that don't most processes eventually write to a page anyways?

I tried to learn about processes that never write to a page but I could not find any examples.

Comment: `However, the thing that I am confused about is that don't most processes eventually write to a page anyways?` No. The executable data, for example, is almost never written to.

Comment: @tkausl When a program assigns a variable memory is written to right? So how can a process ever not write to a page?

Comment: It writes to __one__ page, yes. This copies this one page, all other pages can still be shared though.

Comment: Ok what is happening with the other pages for the process then? Why are they not being written to?

Comment: See my first comment. `The executable data, for example, is almost never written to.`

Comment: Ok. So is the number of pages written to typically in the minority compared to the number of the total pages used by a process? It seems like this would only be a good optimization strategy if the number of pages a typical process writes to is small compared to the total number of pages the process uses.

Comment: `So is the number of pages written to typically in the minority compared to the number of the total pages used by a process?` This depends entirely on what the process is doing.

Comment: @tkausl -- Is there a language translation problem? "*executable data*" is an oxymoron in English. The CPU should never "*execute*" the data. The CPU should execute instructions. Data should be kept separate from instructions (aka code, and a linker may refer to it as the *text* section).

Comment: "*... don't most processes eventually write to a page anyways?*" -- Depends on the program executed by the process. A C program/routine can be written to use local variables, which would be allocated on the stack. Each process has its own stack, and the page(s) that the stack occupies is (already) exclusive to each process.  Presumably the copy-on-write would only apply to the pages allocated for the data section (for static and global variables) of the program and the process's heap.

Comment: As you wrote, `fork()` is expensive, but very often we have a `fork/exec` sequence, so the usual case is to discard all memory at next instruction.

Comment: @sawdust copy-on-write applies to the stack too. Remember, copy-on-write applies to both the parent and child process. Whichever process writes to the stack first will be the one that creates two non-copy-on-write pages from the single copy-on-write page at the current stack position.

Answer (score 1):

Remember what is probably the very most common use case of `fork()`: in combination with one of the `exec()` functions.  Since there is usually only a few lines of code in the child between the fork and the exec, it will likely only write to a very small number of variables, thus touching only a small number of pages.  Those pages must get copied, regardless.  But the vast majority of pages will not be written by the child at all, nor will they be written by the parent in the short time window between `fork` and `exec`.  (Keep in mind that the parent is often doing `wait()` in which case it is also touching very few variables.)  With COW, those pages do not ever need to be copied.

When the child does `exec`, all its memory mappings are destroyed, and the new program is mapped in their place.  At this point, the memory of the parent process is no longer shared with anybody, so the kernel can set it writable again, thus allowing the parent to use it without triggering any copying.

So COW has the effect of making the common case of fork/exec much more efficient, without breaking the uncommon case where the child does do something nontrivial.  And even in the latter case, there is still some savings, because it's likely that the parent and child aren't going to touch *all* of their pages.